# How to move the mouse to any position on the screen, without absolute mouse movements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent

I'm trying to move my mouse in games, which only support raw input. How to move the mouse to a known point?

None of the absolute mouse events have worked in game.
The only one that worked for me was this

```
windll.user32.mouse_event(1, x, y, 0, 0)
```

This function moves the mouse relatively to the current position of the mouse, but I don't know how to move it to a specific pixel.

Comment: How about `win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))`?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It works when I deactivate the raw inputs in one of the games, but it has to work in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try such workaround then:

```
MOUSEEVENT_MOVE = 1 # it's better to keep that as variable

def set_mouse_pos(x, y):
    current_x, current_y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    windll.user32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENT_MOVE, x - current_x, y - current_y, 0, 0)
```